# Exception when opening all VS 2013 solutions after installing .net framework 4.5.2

Tags: visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5

I currently cannot open any of my Visual Studio 2013 solutions. Here's the scenario that happened:

1-  All solutions were working well

2- I tried to open one of the CRM 2015 sample solutions, I received an error message that the `.Net Framework 4.5.2` is required by the solution and not currently installed and asked me if i want to change the framework for the solution to the installed `4.5.1`

3- I started the installation for the .`Net Framework 4.5.2`, it closed all the open instances of Visual Studio and finished installation

4- I tried opening the sample solution again, I received the same error that the .`Net Framework 4.5.2` is not currently installed, and asked me if i want to change the framework for the solution to the installed 4.5.1. I chose to change the solution to 4.5.1

5- The solution opened fine.

6- I tried opening any of my existing VS 2013, none of them worked. But they show the error message `"Visual C++ Language Manager Package" package did not load correctly`, and then VS dialog box "find solutions, close program,.." is shown.

How can I open my solutions again ?

EDIT:

This is the exception details:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: devenv.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 12.0.31101.0
  Problem Signature 03: 54548724
  Problem Signature 04: System.ComponentModel.Composition
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.30319.34209
  Problem Signature 06: 53489a3b
  Problem Signature 07: 16c
  Problem Signature 08: 4f
  Problem Signature 09: JT1X0453KJCJF34Q1KKIEV0ZVYPHQ53A
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 5861
  Additional Information 2: 5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2
  Additional Information 3: a10f
  Additional Information 4: a10ff7d2bb2516fdc753f9c34fc3b069
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran the commands in [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/abcb54bb-5490-48ab-a961-f2c7f64331a3/visual-studio-startup-error-clr20r3?forum=vssetup) answer and it solved my problem:

1.devenv.exe /safemode

2.devenv.exe /resetskippkgs

3.devenv.exe /installvstemplates

4.devenv.exe /resetsettings

5.devenv.exe /resetuserdata